# Redirección a sitios distintos en función del referir y detectar si es mobile o desktop

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Tengo este código en el index.html:

```
<script> 
if (document.referrer.indexOf("ejemplo1.com") != -1 ||
   document.referrer.indexOf("ejemplo2.com") != -1) { 
       window.location =  "http://www.terra.com"; 
   } else {   
       window.location =  "http://www.mypage.com/other-landing/"; 
   } 
</script>
```

Básicamente lo que hace es que si el usuario proviene del dominio ejemplo1.com o ejemplo2.com (cualquiera de los dos) lo va a redirigir automáticamente a terra.com y si no proviene de ninguno de estos dos referers, lo va a llevar a www.mypage.com/other-landing

Hasta aquí todo funciona perfectamente. Pero ahora lo que necesito es añadir una especie de OR, añadiendo nuevos referers pero con redirecciones distintas. Es decir, me gustaría añadir a más a más que si un usuario proviene de ejemplo3.com lo redirija a elpais.com, por ejemplo. Supongo que no tiene mucha complicación añadir esto nuevo, pero no tengo mucha idea de programación y ando perdido ¿Alguien puede copiarme el código que me falta de ejemplo para hacer lo que necesito?

Answer (score -1):

> **Atención**: No es muy buena práctica hacer esto.

Con un switch puedes evaluar con ayuda de expresiones regulares una serie  de posibles ocurrencias.

```
var domain = document.referrer;
var outcome = null;

switch(true) {
    case /ejemplo1.com/.test(domain):
        outcome = "www.terra.com";
        break;
    case /ejemplo2.com/.test(domain):
        outcome = "https://es.stackoverflow.com";
        break;
}
window.location = outcome;
```

La forma normal vendría a ser los clásicos if/else if/else:

```
if(domain.indexOf('ejemplo1.com') !== -1) {

} else if(domain.indexOf('ejemplo2.com') !== -1) {

} else {

}
```

#### Actualización

Si quieres determinar si se está visualizando desde móvil, puedes usar la librería [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ismobilejs/0.4.0/isMobile.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if(isMobile.any) {
        // redireccionar
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto. Millones de gracias. Pero por qué dices que no es muy buena práctica hacer esto? sólo he añadido y utilizado el trozo del final, no el primero. Sólo con lo del else if ya me ha funcionado sin necesidad de hacer nada de lo del switch, hay alguna diferencia entre una cosa u otra?

Comment: La estructura switch se usa pensando en evaluar un valor y colocar un case por cada posible coincidencia. En el switch que he puesto, no hay valor a evaluar porque siempre es true, solo es un truco para poder utilizar en los case expresiones regulares. La forma "normal" es la segunda, pero la primera es funcional también.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por cierto, lo último que me falta es poder hacer lo mismo (redirigir) en función del referer (que es lo que está ahora) pero en algunos casos necesito tener en cuenta también si es tráfico desktop o mobile. Se puede dar el caso de que el referer coincida con otro caso anterior, es decir, el tráfico mobile de ejemplo1.com lo redirijo a terra.com, pero el tráfico desktop de ejemplo2.com lo redirijo a stackoverflow.com. Cómo puedo hacer esto siguiendo la estructura que he hecho? Muchísimas gracias...

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta para el tema móvil. Por favor, actualiza tu pregunta indicando que también quieres saber si el usuario está desde móvil para que tu pregunta y mi respuesta coincidan :) No olvides marcar la respuesta  como correcta si así te parece. Saludos.

Comment: Editada. Te he agregado a Skype, me gustaría hablar contigo cuándo puedas. Gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué skype? No recuerdo mi cuenta xD. Entra al [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39741/java-jvm) que casi siempre me encuentras allí.

Comment: no me deja chatear porque no tengo suficiente reputación lol :-( , hay alguna forma de que podamos hablar? me gustaría hacerte una propuesta sin compromiso, gracias!!

Comment: Mi email: mitsu.gami.pe@gmail.com

Comment: Email enviado ;-)